# Subscript out of Range error, when Watch shows it is definitely in range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, debugging

I have the following code that throws an error "subscript out of range"

```vb
        ' Populate the Combo Box
        For i = 0 To GetArrayLastIndex(ar(0))
            With Sheet1.Line_Items
                .AddItem
                .List(i, 0) = ar(0, i)
                .List(i, 1) = ar(1, i)
            End With
        Next i


'Function:

Public Function GetArrayLastIndex(a As Variant) As Long
   If IsEmpty(a) Then
      GetArrayLastIndex = 0
   Else
      GetArrayLastIndex = UBound(a) - LBound(a)
   End If
End Function
```

But looking at the Watch below, it looks like `ar(0)` should be an array, and not out of range.

What is happening and how can I fix this?

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
Option Explicit



Private Sub Line_Items_Change()

    Dim ar As Variant

    Dim i As Integer

    ar = GetSerialNumber(Sheet1.Line_Items.Value)

    With Sheet1.SerialNumber
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;60"
    End With

    ' Populate the Combo Box
    For i = 0 To GetArrayLastIndex(ar(0))
    With Sheet1.SerialNumber
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = ar(0, i)
        .List(i, 1) = ar(1, i)
    End With
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub SerialNumber_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim i As Integer


    If Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
        ar = GetOrder(Target.Value)
        Sheet1.Line_Items.Clear

        With Sheet1.Line_Items
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0;60"
        .Clear
        End With

        ' Populate the Combo Box
        For i = 0 To GetArrayLastIndex(ar(0))
        With Sheet1.Line_Items
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = ar(0, i)
            .List(i, 1) = ar(1, i)
        End With
        Next i



    End If
End Sub

Function GetOrder(OrderNo As Long) As Variant

    Const CONN = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=;UID=excel;PWD=; OPTION=3"

    Const SQL = "select id, description from item where order.number = ?"

    Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection, dbCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter, n As Long

    Set dbConn = New ADODB.Connection
    dbConn.Open CONN

    Set dbCmd = New ADODB.Command
    With dbCmd
    .ActiveConnection = dbConn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = SQL
    Set param = .CreateParameter("P1", adInteger, adParamInput, 0)
    .Parameters.Append param
    End With

    Set rs = dbCmd.Execute(n, OrderNo)

    If Not rs.EOF Then
       GetOrder = rs.GetRows
    Else
    GetOrder = Array(Array("#N/A"), Array("#N/A"))
    MsgBox "Could not find order #" & OrderNo, vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If
    dbConn.Close

End Function


Function GetSerialNumber(SerialNumber As Long) As Variant

    Const CONN = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=;UID=excel;PWD=; OPTION=3"

    Const SQL = "SELECT serial FROM table WHERE id = ? ORDER BY serial"

    Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection, dbCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter, n As Long

    Set dbConn = New ADODB.Connection
    dbConn.Open CONN

    Set dbCmd = New ADODB.Command
    With dbCmd
    .ActiveConnection = dbConn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = SQL
    Set param = .CreateParameter("P1", adInteger, adParamInput, 0)
    .Parameters.Append param
    End With

    Set rs = dbCmd.Execute(n, SerialNumber)

    If Not rs.EOF Then
    GetSerialNumber = rs.GetRows
    Else
    GetSerialNumber = Array(Array("#N/A", "#N/A"))
    MsgBox "Could not find order #" & SerialNumber, vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If
    dbConn.Close

End Function


Public Function GetArrayLastIndex(a As Variant) As Long
   If IsEmpty(a) Then
      GetArrayLastIndex = 0
   Else
      GetArrayLastIndex = UBound(a) - LBound(a)
   End If
End Function
```

**Ubound(2) doesn't work in another situation**

Code and error message:

[image]

Comment: Your array is a 2d array, if you want the Ubound of the second dimension you need `Ubound(a,2) - Lbound(a,2)` and you would pass the whole array `GetArrayLastIndex(ar)`

Comment: Could you share the complete code?

Comment: added complete code

Comment: `GetSerialNumber = rs.GetRows` returns a 2D array not an array of arrays(jagged array)

Comment: Yes ... does that require different code?  I've also added **"Ubound(2) doesn't work in another situation"** title to my question where I get another subscript error when I try using `Ubound(a, 2)`.  What could be wrong there?

Comment: I recast array as 2D array and it is working better